# Deducing column from User defined range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

Edit: @TimWilliams  I edited the code as follows but it it doesn't run at all now.  ANy thoughts?

```
Sub Item_Fix()

Dim rng As Range, col As Range, arr
Dim sht As Worksheet, c As Range, tmp

On Error Resume Next 'in case user cancels
Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
            Prompt:="Please select the Items to update. " & _
                    " (e.g. Column A or Column B)", _
            Title:="Select Range", Type:=8)

On Error GoTo 0

  '  Set hdr = Application.InputBox( _
  '              Prompt:="Does your selection contain headers?", _
  '              Title:="Header Option")

hdr = MsgBox("Does your selection contain a header?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Header Option")

If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Please select only a single column!", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Set sht = rng.Parent
Set col = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, rng.Column), _
                    sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If hdr = vbYes Then
    For Each c In col.Cells
    tmp = Trim(c.Value)
    If Len(tmp) > 0 And Len(tmp) < 9 And Row > 1 Then
        c.NumberFormat = "@"
        c.Value = Right("000000000" & tmp, 9)
    End If
Next c
End If
If hdr = vbNo Then
    For Each c In col.Cells
    tmp = Trim(c.Value)
    If Len(tmp) > 0 And Len(tmp) < 9 Then
        c.NumberFormat = "@"
        c.Value = Right("000000000" & tmp, 9)
    End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

I'm trying to write a function that will insert leading zeroes into a column that a user specifies.   Honestly, I would love for this to be like the Excel Menu Data > Remove Duplicates option.  I want to click on a menu button and then select my range and let it do the magic, unfortunately I keep getting errors when trying to deduce the column that has been selected.  Other than that issue, it should work fine.  My code is below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Item_Fix()
'Set Item = Application.InputBox("Select the range that contains the Items").Column
Set IC = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                "Please select the Range of Items.  (e.g. Column A or Column B)", _
                    Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8).Column
'Set Items = vRange.Column
Set Items = IC.Column
Lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Items.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
For i = 2 To Lastrow
Cells(i, Items + 1).Formula = "=Text(" & Cells(i, Items) & ",""000000000"")"
Next i
NewColumn = Items + 1
NewColumn.EntireColumn.Copy
Items.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
NewColumn.EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want a textual representation of a number 9 characters long with leading zeroes or a custom number format that retains the underlying true number value but displays it as 9 digits long with leading zeroes? Wouldn't it be easier to the user to preselect the cells to receive the procedure and click a button like making cells bold?

Comment: That's a great question.  Thanks for asking!  I need it to be text that is 9 characters long, inserting leading zeroes until the length is 9.  The custom number format will not work due to future formulas that will be using the column 'Items'.  

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `Column` will return a number, so drop the `Set` at the beginning of that line.  However if the user doesn't select a range it would result in a run-time error.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, I still get the type mismatch error at this line:

    Set Items = IC
.
Any thoughts?

Comment: As I noted `Column` returns a *numeric value* (the column index on the sheet), not a Range.  If you want a range then use `EntireColumn`

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for getting back with me.  I tried using EntireColumn as well; however, I get an object defined error.  I will keep playing with it though.  Jeeped has made a far more efficient script that I could use, but I also want to see what I could do to make my original one work as I like to know various methods.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jeeped has the right approach I think, but since you asked for a version of your original...

```
Sub Item_Fix()

    Dim rng As Range, col As Range, arr
    Dim sht As Worksheet, c As Range, tmp

    On Error Resume Next 'in case user cancels
    Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
                Prompt:="Please select the Items to update. " & _
                        " (e.g. Column A or Column B)", _
                Title:="Select Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select only a single column!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set sht = rng.Parent
    Set col = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, rng.Column), _
                        sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In col.Cells
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 And Len(tmp) < 9 Then
            c.NumberFormat = "@"
            c.Value = Right("000000000" & tmp, 9)
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was trying to do.  I also love the msgbox if they select more than 1 column!  That's great.  Thank you both so much!  What I will try to do now is follow your lead and add another message box asking if there are column headers.  IF there is a column header, then i'll edit it to:

    If Len(tmp) > 0 And Len(tmp) < 9 and c > 1 Then....


    I'll paste my results when I get it working.  Thanks again.  That looks great!

Answer (score 0):

Let the user select a group of cells to receive the procedure. An [InputBox method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195768%28v=office.11%29.aspx) seems like one extra step and an impediment to the workflow.

```
Sub make_DUNS_number()
    Dim duns As Range, tmp As String
    For Each duns In Selection
        'possible error control on non-numeric values
        'if isnumeric(duns.value2) then
            tmp = Right("000000000" & Format(duns.Value2, "000000000;@"), 9)
            duns.NumberFormat = "@"
            duns.Value2 = tmp
        'end if
    Next duns
End Sub
```

With that in place, you should have no trouble adding it to the QAT. See [Add Buttons to the Quick Access Toolbar and Customize Button Images](http://blogs.office.com/2009/07/17/add-buttons-to-the-quick-access-toolbar-and-customize-button-images/) for more information.

Comment: that works beautifully!  Thank you so much.  Also, I understand what you mean about.  InputBox method adding extra steps, but it's for some of my new employees that will need some automation and some assistance.  I personally don't mind using the text formula, but I also love learning VBA.  Would it still be possible to have the script run based on a user's mouse selected range inserted via inputbox?

Comment: Look at the *Default* parameter in the [InputBox method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195768%28v=office.11%29.aspx) link I supplied. TBH, if a user can make a selection of cells bold or underlined without an InputBox, why can't they do the same thing for a nine character number with leading zeroes? It seems like you are asking them to learn a new method rather than adapting one that has already been learned.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check that out right now.  

I understand where you're coming from.  Honestly, some departments have given opportunity to less fortunate and uneducated workers and please believe me when I say that having them click a macro button, then click on the range as it tells them to will be far easier then them remembering to select a valid range and then click on the macro.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I used to encourage office managers to allow their employees to play Solitaire during their lunch breaks. While doing so they learned click, drag and double-click and became more valued employees (all on their own time). The next version of Windows brough MineSweeper and everyone learned how to right-click. Then came Hearts and all the employees spent their lunch breaks learning how to network. All of these learned skills were directly transferrable to their jobs because *Windows uses common methods throughout all programs*.

Comment: This is such a great comment! I love it.

Comment: Not my first rodeo.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection = Evaluate("index(text(" & Selection.Address & ",""'000000000""),,1)")
```